# Unable to find specification for '$PODNAME'

Tags: xcode, macos, cocoapods, podfile

Below is my podfile

```
platform :ios, '11.0'

source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'

project '/Users/sylvanm/Desktop/Programming/Xcode/Practice/First Apps on   phone/iMango/iMango.xcodeproj'

target 'iMango' do
   pod 'iMango'
end
```

It says `[!] Unable to find a specification for iMango`
(there are the '' marks around iMango but idk how to format that.

Please help!

Comment: Hi Sylvan, can you provide more info about the error

Comment: What has this to do with `bash`?

Comment: `pod 'iMango'` Are you sure? That's the name of your pod? I didn't find it there: https://cocoapods.org/?q=iMango